# How to import the files from folder A to folder B with latest version of folder A

Tags: clearcase

In clearcase v9.0.1.5, I need to import files from folder A to new folder B with the latest version of A.

Meaning: the ClearCase versions of files in B should be same as that of A:
if file version in A is 4 then after import the version of that file should show as 4 in B.

Is there any possibility to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm) to [import flat files to a branch](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228449) in one command.
That will duplicate the files from A to B, versioning them again in B.

But that won't duplicate the version number, which entirely depends on the history of the branch.

You can use [`cleartool checkin -identical`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21255834) to force an element to increment its version number on its branch.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understood your point. Is there any possibility in clearcase to update the version of the file to later version (example, from file version 1 to 5)

Comment: @Chandrashekar Not that I know of, beside artificially doing a `cleartool checkin --identical`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If folders A and B are in the same VOB, you can hard link the files together, but that will have issues with checkouts in dynamic views. You could also create use symlinks.

If A and B are in separate NON-UCM VOBs,you can use clearexport_ccase and clearimport to copy the elements.

Another option for non UCM VOBs is to use relocate -update to copy the files. This clones the relocated elements completely, down to their OIDs. If A and B will be used in the same audited build, you probably dont want to do this as some directory OIDs may get cloned too, and directory element OIDs are used heavily in build audits.

For UCM component VOBS, you may have to DIY it using scripts. "Cleartool checkin -from" may help here.